# Лямбда выражение или...что?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, синтаксис

В проекте, в определении класса  встретил код:

```
 public ICollection<Group> UserGroups { get; set; }

 public UserGroup[] Groups =>
        (from _ in this.UserGroups select new UserGroup { 
            Display=_.DisplayName,
            Value=_.Id.ToString()
        }).ToArray<UserGroup>();
```

Не соображу что тут делают с Groups. В скобках у нас linq запрос, который формирует массив объектов UserGroup. А вот причём здесь оператор => и какую он выполняет роль - не ясно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это синтаксис свежей версии C# 6.0.

`public UserGroup[] Groups` объявление св-ва, а после оператора `=>` его геттер. Т.е. теперь лямбдой, можно определять свойства и методы. А в следующей версии можно будет и конструктор.

Эквивалент в старой версии

```
public UserGroup[] Groups
{
   get 
   {
       return
         (from _ in this.UserGroups select new UserGroup 
           { 
              Display=_.DisplayName,
              Value=_.Id.ToString()
           }
         ).ToArray<UserGroup>();
   }
}
```

Comment: [Expression bodies on property-like function members](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodies-on-property-like-function-members)

Comment: Получается, что сеттер у нас здесь не определён и мы не можем изменить значение свойства, можем только его получить. Верно?

Comment: @Дмитрий, верно. Но по указанной в вашем фрагменте логике мы и не должны менять  значение свойства через него само. Значение меняется при изменении `UserGroups`, а  `Groups` лишь его представление и оно только для чтения.

Comment: 4per спасибо большое, что так доступно объяснили! Grundy, благодарю за ссылку на статью!